# Text-align: center; ignored for display: flex element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For the following the anchor text isn't centered. If I change the anchor's display from flex to block then the text is centered. Why is this?

Ive only tested on Chrome so far.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>



*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit- box-sizing: border-box;   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgmbH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: Before you go ahead to read my answer, I would like you to
>   notify that am not using any of the PROPRIETARY PREFIXES, if it
>   doesn't work for you, its time to update your browser, or try adding
>   the prefixes like `-moz` or `-webkit` and see if it works for you.

The correct way to do is to use `display: flex;` for the `ul` element and `flex-grow` on `li` elements...

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oHeLy)</kbd>

You are using a fixed width on `a` tag i.e `width: 200px;` and that kills the idea of flex layout, so take that out, and alter your CSS with the one provided by me.

Here, I've used `flex-grow` with a value of `1` so that each of the `li` element shares the equal amount of `width`

---

If you are looking to wrap the cells if they exceed the containers width, than you need to use the following properties on `ul` element like

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Aojvl)</kbd> *(Resize your window to see the effect)*

[image]

Sample 1, the wrapped element will stretch to full width

---

[image]

Sample 2, Elements wrapped equally further

Also note that am using `min-width: 100px;` on `li` elements to force wrap in the demonstration

---

As you commented that you wanted three li on each row, than instead of using `flex-grow: 1;` you need to use `flex: 1 1 33%;` like

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 100px;
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HIuaA)</kbd>

[image]

Sample 3, Equal number of li on each row

[image]

Sample 4, Equal number of li on each row even when resized

On further resize, they will accommodate automatically say two in a row and one in a row..

Comment: Is there a way I can make the li's wrap onto 2 rows. So effectively make each one double the size compared to how it is in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the update, made your answer even better! However what I was actually asking is if you could make the first 3 lis be on one row and the next 3 drop to the next line. And keep them as full width. Thanks

Comment: @jdln Why not use floats then? Should I provide a demo? or display: table would be better in terms of support, shouldn't go with flex if thats your requirement

Comment: The anchor text length varies but I need each link to be the same height. The site is responsive and the link text is dynamic so I cant set a px height.

Comment: One of my reasons for using flex layout is that display table can make the links the same height, but it cant have them wrapping into 2 rows.

Comment: @jdln cool, thats fine, so instead of using `flex-grow` replace it with `flex: 1 1 33.33%;` and you are done